# regex expression help for two or more decimal places

Tags: c#, regex, replaceall

Using c# I am trying to replace text in richtextbox that has two or more decimal places. In particular I am looking for Regex expression for two to four decimal places.

if someone can assist with this. I would appreciate it. I tried numerous regex expression, most of which did not work

Comment: It's best to show what you tried.

Comment: @RedLaser That's 2 to 4 periods, I think the OP means numbers after a decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\d+\.\d{2,4}` will match numbers with two to four decimals.
`\d+\.\d{2,}` will match numbers with two and more decimals.

Note that you should not use regex here if you can avoid. You will disregard localization and won't easily be able to round (if that's what you want).

Comment: Should note this won't match if there isn't at least one number before the decimal like ".05"

Comment: @juharr yeah, most people write the leading 0 so I didn't mention it, but replacing the `+` by a `*` and prefixing the pattern with a `^` would make it work with your format.